# Does Android systrace require root access?

Tags: android, systrace

I am trying to run systrace on a non-rooted device. It always gives the following error if any of the trace events is selected:

**Unable to find trace start marker 'TRACE:': error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/cpufreq_interactive/enable: No such file or directory**

If no trace event is selected, it works, but the trace is not very usweful.

Does systrace requires root access?

Note that I am running systrace directly from Eclipse (DDMS) on Windows-7.

Answer (score 3):

According to `systrace.py --help`, the following traces require root access:

- **-d, --disk:** trace disk I/O (requires root)
- **-u, --bus-utilization:** trace bus utilization (requires root)
- **-w, --workqueue:** trace the kernel workqueues (requires root)

The other options don't specify that a root access is required.

This said, I can use some of the traces (such as **`--cpu-freq`**), but I am unfortunately interested in **`--cpu-load`** which gives me the very same error as you mentioned.