# How do I monitor the usage by CPU on Android?

Tags: android, monitoring, cpu-usage, multicore

I know that I can monitor the total usage by using, for instance:

```
adb top -m 10
```

But I would be interested in monitoring each CPU separately. Using top on Linux, I can use the interactive command '1' to show the usage for each CPU separately. How can I do this on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can:

```
# top -h
Usage: top [ -m max_procs ] [ -n iterations ] [ -d delay ] [ -s sort_column ] [ -t ] [ -h ]
    -m num  Maximum number of processes to display.
    -n num  Updates to show before exiting.
    -d num  Seconds to wait between updates.
    -s col  Column to sort by (cpu,vss,rss,thr).
    -t      Show threads instead of processes.
    -h      Display this help screen.
```

You could use [systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html) to track execution time of processes per cpu. Also see [Analyzing Display and Performance with Systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html). If you have a rooted device busybox might have a more complete implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the proposition, but systrace does not work for the cpu-load (same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810460/does-android-systrace-require-root-access). And I would like to get numbers, when it gives me a weird HTML interactive page =/